# Image Source WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a 2 Image Controls in my WPF Application,
I have a List of Image, I want to assign the images from the List to multiple controls.

```
imgBackground= t.BackgroundImage //Only shows in one component don't work
imgBackground.Source  = t.BackgroundImage.Source ;//don't work
```

The Image is not showing in all the Image control i try to assign it to.
How can i fix this?

Note t.BackgroundImage and imgBackground is of type System.Windows.Controls.Image

Comment: Can you include the definitions for imgBackground and BackgroundImage

Comment: Please describe a bit more detailed what exactly does not work and which error occurs.

Comment: Both Are Of System.Windows.Controls.Image basic wpf image control

Comment: @Spontificus it does not work, Their i know error, I have assigned the same image source in two places one is showing other one is not.

Comment: @Taufiq does it simply not work or is an exception occurring?

Comment: Can show XAML and code behind?